# Separating a given sentence thats in an array to words in separate arrays

Tags: c, arrays

This was a given lab and the goal of the lab is to get the users first, middle, and last name all in one string. Then separate the string into 3 other strings which will hold the first, middle, and last name. I must use strlen(), strchr(), and strcpy(). I know the code is not the prettiest nor the best way to do it. My professor wanted us to do it this way.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FU_LIMIT 37
#define FI_LIMIT 13
#define MI_LIMIT 13
#define LA_LIMIT 13


void fill_array(char full_ar[]);
void get_full_name(char full_ar[], char first_ar[]);
void ch_search();
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char full_ar[FU_LIMIT], first_ar[FI_LIMIT], middle_ar[MI_LIMIT],     last_ar[LA_LIMIT];
int start;
    get_full_name( full_ar, first_ar);
for (start = 0; start < 1; start++ )
{

    printf("First: %s\n", first_ar);
    printf("Middle: %s\n", middle_ar);
    printf("Last: %s\n", last_ar);
    printf("%s\n", full_ar);

}

return 0;
}

void fill_array(char full_ar[]) //passed array and characters to fill with, returns number of writes
{
char start;
for (start = 0; start < 36; start++)
    //for loop starts here and performs a test
{
    full_ar[start] = 0;
}


}

void get_full_name(char full_ar[], char first_ar[]) //passed array to put name in, returns nothing
{
    printf("Please enter your First, Middle, and Last Name:\n");
scanf("%36[^\n]s", full_ar);

for( int i=0 ; i < 37 ; ++i ) full_ar[i] = toupper( full_ar[i] ) ;



 }

void ch_search()//passed array to search, char to search for, length of  array
{


}
```

So what I am asking is for help using the functions strlen(), strchr(), and strcpy() to help separate the full name array into First, Middle, and Last.

Comment: Your question is very broad, try starting with reading a bit about the functions in question and then asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your string is always delimited by spaces. In the loop (lower bound = 0, upper bound = strlen() -1 ) search for spaces and maintain the index of the last non-space character so that when you find a space (using strchr) you will have a beginning and ending index to use in strcpy.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that? Should I actually use strchr in my loop?

Comment: Yes.  Here are more characters so StackOverflow will accept this comment.

Comment: so I would do in my for loop
    (start = 0; start < 1; start++, strlen( ))